# Do I understand correctly the C syntax?

Tags: c

I have this syntax:

```
double (*(f(double (*)(int))))(int);
```

Do I understand correctly syntax above that f is function that gets pointer to function that receive int and return a double?

Answer (score 4):

No; it's actually even more complicated than that.

[cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/) glosses this type definition as:

> declare f as function (pointer to function (int) returning double) returning pointer to function (int) returning double

In other words, the function pointed to by `f` takes a function pointer as an argument, and returns a function pointer. Both of those function pointers must be to functions which take an `int` as an argument and return a `double`.

You could simplify this definition a bit using an intermediate `typedef` as follows:

```
typedef double (*int_to_double_function)(int);
int_to_double_function (*f)(int_to_double_function);
```